# Функция возвращает некорректные данные

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь сделать GET запрос, но Qt говорит, что `getData` должен возвращать `int`, хотя я не делаю `return`.

```
#include "downloader.h"

Downloader::Downloader(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
     manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
}

Downloader::getData()
{
    QUrl url("http://www.mtbank.by/currxml.php");
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(url);
    manager->get(request);
}


class Downloader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Downloader(QObject *parent = 0);

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;

public slots:
    void getData();
};
```

Текст ошибки:

> ```
> prototype for 'int Downloader::getData()' does not match any class 'Downloader'
> in file included from ../untitled2/downloader.cpp:1:0:
> candidate is: voidDownloader::getData()
>         void getData();
>              ^
> ```

Comment: `Downloader::getData()` - что это такое? Куда вдруг делся ваш `void`?

Comment: Приведите дословный текст сообщения от компилятора.

Answer (score 3):

Если функция объявлена так, что возвращает не `void` - стандарт прямо требует, чтобы в ней все пути выполнения оканчивались `return`, либо `throw`, либо остановкой процесса. Функция не может заканчиваться "ничем".

Исключения - функция `main`. Отсутствие явного возврата из нее эквивалентно `return 0;`

В связи с дополнением вопроса:

Из текста ошибки следует, что у вас сигнатура реализации не совпадает с сигнатурой декларации. Сделайте, чтобы совпадало:

```
class Downloader ...
{
     void Downloader::getData()
}

....

void Downloader::getData()
{
}
```

Comment: ну так я явно задал void, а компилятор говорит чтобы я сделал его Int

Comment: елы палы, как все сложно.. и как быть?

Comment: @Radzhab про виртуальный метод я угадал неправильно. Показывайте тексты ошибок.

Comment: Откуда Вы взяли про требование `return` по всем путям? Нет такого в Стандарте. Даже компилятор дает на это всего лишь предупреждение, а не ошибку. Насколько я помню, объясняется это возможностью возвращать значение например через ассемблерные вставки. А вот не указывать явно *тип* возврата функции действительно нельзя, в сях подразумевался неявный `int`, в плюсах такое уже не разрешено.

Comment: @alexolut Если функция не заканчивается return, но что-то должна вернуть, будет UB.

Comment: @gbg не обязательно. Можно и по `exit` выйти или через исключение.

Comment: @alexolut В любом случае, должен быть записан явный выход.